# removing a shard from mongo database

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to remove a shard from a Mongo shard (v3.2) - I cannot see any database names that I need to remove but the draining process is not ending which I am guessing is because its waiting for user action to fix something.  Based on the error message, can anyone figure out how to further troubelshoot this issue?

```
db.runCommand( { removeShard : "shard0001" } )
{
    "msg" : "draining ongoing",
    "state" : "ongoing",
    "remaining" : {
        "chunks" : NumberLong(1),
        "dbs" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "note" : "you need to drop or movePrimary these databases",
    "dbsToMove" : [ ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting all test databases/collections that I did not need resolved the issue.  Doing that in a non-test environment would not be the best approach.  Still looking for a better solution.